# Android background Runnable app

Tags: android

I am beginner in android development. I want to implement a app which send request to my server for checking server load.after receiving server response it should alert to user if load is higher than predefined value..Ok i have done this.
now i have implemented this,but i have to run my app eveytime.

But my app should be run in background,means like whats app.user will get notifications without running their app.

It should send request,notify user even if app is not running.

anyone has idea please suggest me..

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to work with the `Service`s in android. For the Notifications thing,you will need to learn `GCM server` functionality

- For Gcm server Functionality [See this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)
- and [For learning about services,](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html)

Services are something that will run in background for you,Give an eye to the above links and you will learn how to use them

Comment: you can also use sync adapter